# Is there a way my action work on my second site?

Tags: php, wordpress, function, woocommerce, multisite

I created a multisite and have woocommerce set on both sites. I created an action hook on the functions.php which is working on the primary website but is not working on the second site on the network. I have various actions that are not working on the second site. Currently, the woocommerce is not network activated. I have tried network activating woocommerce but it still does not work.

Tried using

```
function forsitetwo() {
    if ( get_current_blog_id() === 2 ){

add_action( 'woocommerce_before_checkout_form', 'order_summary' );
        function order_summary() {
          echo '<div class="g-cols wpb_row type_default valign_top vc_inner  vc_custom_1549298472435" id="order_summary">
            <div class="vc_col-sm-12 wpb_column vc_column_container">
              <div class="vc_column-inner  vc_custom_1544731999039">
                <div class="wpb_wrapper">
                <h2 style="color: #ee2d63;text-align: left" class="vc_custom_heading">Summary of your order</h2>
                    <div class="wpb_text_column ">
                        <div class="wpb_wrapper">
                            <p>Thank you for choosing to advertise with Nuestra Vision. Please review your order and follow the prompts to complete your purchase. If you have any questions or concerns, please contact us at 1-888-688-8181 or through the chat window below.</p>
                      <p><input class="w-btn us-btn-style_1 icon_none" type="button" id="backto_btn" value="Back To Packages" onclick="history.back()"></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>';
        }

}
```

I am expecting the custom summary to show up as it does on the primary website. This just one of the actions. I believe if I fix one then I will be able to fix the others

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. So if you are using a multisite you want to access via FTP a folder called mu-plugins. There you would create a new php file and add your actions in that file. Now your actions should be working.

Reference: https://bjornjohansen.no/mu-plugins